# Android Development: How can I keep screen on when the activity of my app is at background?

Tags: android

I have tried the following code:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

However, it only works when the program is on screen.

My app will launch Chrome to visit a website and it becomes background. At this time, it doesn't work.

If I want to keep the screen on when I launch my app, even though it may be at background, how can I do to implement it?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the screen on when the user is browsing in Chrome? After all, the user is then welcome to visit a different Web site, or leave Chrome entirely and go do something else.

Comment: Do you want a `WakeLock`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: It may launch other apps, such as music player or something. I just want to keep screen on to simulate the daily using of a phone. So I must keep the screen on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a class that extends service then add

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

It will run on background even your app is not on screen. You can also use wakelock. You can see a good tutorial [here](http://thiranjith.com/2012/02/22/android-prevent-screen-timeout/#chitika_close_button).